# How to insert and call new data in wordpress website database through a plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database

I have a dropbox button that user interact with it to get some data like video's id and video's name using Js code.

What I want to do is insert these data in the database using `pair` data structure and calling it in when it needed.

I found out that I can do this using `add_metadata` or `add_options` which one shoukd i use? and is there better sutiable way.

Second thing: I have the button here implemented through `add_shortcode` using a tag but I want to replace the tag with html class in the page because I've to to write the tag like `[]` to add the button.

[image: The button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right place to store the data depends on how you will be using the data. From the context, it sounds like metadata might be the right place. There is `usermeta` if the data relates to one of your site users, or `postmeta` if the data relates to a specific post/page/CPT.

Options are best reserved for data that affects the site as a whole. So, if you were going to use the data to populate a video that appears sitewide, `options` would be an appropriate place to store the data. But the `options` table can tend to get bloated and impact site performance, so it's especially inappropriate if the data doesn't relate to the site as a whole, or a large part of the site.

Comment: Thanks this's very clear, but now for this data that I want to insert should I create the new columns for the data manually? or can I create just one time in the code? because these data is new functionality that not have prefix in wordpress database. May I ask for the other part can I use `add_shortcode` with with a html class for example if I have specfic html class in a wordpress website page can I use instead of doing and adding `[tagname]` in the page then pass the name to `add_shortcode` function? –

Comment: Adding metadata or options does not require creating any new columns in the database. You simply use `add_user_meta()`, `add_post_meta()`, or `add_option()` and WP stores it within its existing columns in existing tables. It is possible to add your own custom tables to store plugin data if you have a lot to store. For the shortcode question, I would recommend asking a new WPSE question as the site is really built to handle one question/answer pair at a time. :)

Comment: For example the default wp_usermeta has 4 columns, now if i want to insert my new data then I have to create my new colums but for a plugin dev sake this will be absurd if it's gonna be done manually. So I think i need to create using the code just one time run. Am I correct or am i missing something?

Comment: No, when you insert your data you would do it within the existing columns. The `meta_key` will be the name you call the data, and the `meta_value` is the actual data itself. There is rarely a need to extend Core tables, and it's usually wiser to add a separate table rather than change any Core db structure.